# Load second URL if first is not present in android webView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

I was making a webview application for my local network. I have two static IPs. All I want to do is to load second if 1st one is down. (Because one of them is always running).

What I'm doing is to check it in `onRecievedError()` function and change the URL value, then call the `onCreate()` again like this.

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    url1="http://192.168.43.XXX";  //here XXX is used just to hide my IP from public
    onCreate(new Bundle());
}
```

the `onCreate()` method has to render the new URL but my application closes itself upon this call. Why is this so?
Please help because I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use this code**

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(failingUrl.equals(url1))
        {
            //you can use load url if fail first url
            // dont't use onCreate again
            webview.loadUrl(url2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm calling that again because I have done a lot of other things like download and upload handler in it.